# Only get appointed term's count?

Tags: elasticsearch

I `analyzed` a filed,so there will be a lot of terms.

Now,i just want to get the count of the terms which i cared about.For example,i just want to know the count of `word1` and `word2`.

Is there any term search grammar?

Comment: did you check https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-termvectors.html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should query and aggregate them, and make include for what you want

```
{
  "query": {
    "terms": {
      "YourField_HERE": [
        "word1",
        "word2"
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "genres": {
      "terms": {
        "include" : ["word1", "word2"]
        "field": "YourField_HERE"
      }
    }
  }
}
```